# How to pass args to the parallel foreach

Tags: multithreading, powershell-workflow

I get list of endpoints as arguments to my script, I want to send http request to all of them, but I don't want to do it in sequence, but rather simultaneously. I found that there is something like parallel foreach, however I can't access my `args` there.

```
$errors = @()

workflow a {
    foreach -Parallel ($endpoint in $args) { 
        $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($endpoint)

        try {
            $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
            $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

            if ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
                Write-Host "OK"
            }
        } catch {
            $errors += $endpoint + ": " + $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** How send this HTTP request in parallel mode?

Answer (score 3):

`foreach -parallel` is a [PowerShell Workflow](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/08/19/powershell-workflow-for-mere-mortals-part-1/) construct. Workflows are not to be confused with regular PowerShell because they use a different engine that works [subtly differently](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions/).

But first of all, you need to actually invoke the workflow. The code you posted just defines it without ever invoking it. Next, there are several issues with your code due to the aforementioned differences:

- The automatic variable `$args` is not available in workflows. Instead you must define the parameters your workflow should accept.
- The `Write-Host` cmdlet is not available in workflows. Instead use `Write-Verbose` or `Write-Debug` for status output.
- You cannot update variables defined outside the workflow from inside the workflow. Instead collect the output of the workflow in a variable.

```bsh
# define the workflow
workflow a {
    Param($endpointList)

    foreach -parallel ($endpoint in $endpoint_list) {
        Write-Output $endpoint     # <-- workflow will return this
        'something'                # <-- this too
        ...
    }
}

# invoke the workflow and collect its output
$errors = a 'https://example.org/foo', 'https://example.com/bar', ...
```

Comment: This is very helpful, however how to return something from the workflow?

Comment: @Yoda Simply output what you want returned inside the workflow (e.g. via `Write-Output`) and collect that output as shown in my answer.